# Redis - JUnit - Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: localhost

Tags: java, junit, redis

I have a SpringBoot application where I connect to Redis and it works on cloud environment:

```
 RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
 redisStandaloneConfiguration.setHostName("localhost");
 redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPort(6379);
 redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPassword(REDIS_PASSWORD);
 LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory = new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration, clientConfig);
 lettuceConnectionFactory.setValidateConnection(true);
```

Now i started a local Redis instance on localhost and port 6379; I tried to write a Junit test that uses Redis and I got the following
exception

```
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to  localhost:6379
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:78)
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:56)
    at io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisClient.getConnection(AbstractRedisClient.java:320)
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisClient.connect(RedisClient.java:211)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.StandaloneConnectionProvider.lambda$getConnection$1(StandaloneConnectionProvider.java:115)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.StandaloneConnectionProvider.getConnection(StandaloneConnectionProvider.java:115)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$ExceptionTranslatingConnectionProvider.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1459)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException:  localhost
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1281)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1193)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1077)
```

Any hints?

I tried:

- localhost
- 127.0.0.1
- put localhost 127.0.0.1 in hosts file

But got the same exception

Comment: can you try with the ip address returned from "ipconfig" command? Also, are you trying to connect via proxy in code level? If so, pls try disabling proxy..

Comment: Yes, I tried all the Ips shown in ipconfig output:
10.0.0.5, 10.223.252.108,192.168.56.1

Comment: can you please share the output of this command  
netstat -aon | find /i "listening" |find "6379"

Comment: TCP    0.0.0.0:6379           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       14984

Comment: can you please try updating "redis.conf" file with "protected-mode" property from yes to no?

Comment: Running redis-cli gives me below output with hostname & Port # as part of it. Can you please share what do you see in your case? Thank you!

127.0.0.1:6379>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hours I found the problem:

```
redis.cluster.nodes:${REDIS_CLUSTER_NODES: localhost:6379;}
```

If I put

```
redis.cluster.nodes: localhost:6379;
```

it works fine